# Properties of Exponential Matrix

Tags: matrices, power-series, exponential-function, matrix-calculus

One of the properties is that $e^{{\bf A}+{\bf B}}\neq e^{\bf A}e^{\bf B}$ unless ${\bf AB}$$={\bf BA}$. Can someone please explain how exactly commutativity matters in this case? I'm guessing it has something to do with series multiplication?

Comment: In a commutative ring, you have the binomial theorem. With that, some algebra, and an interchange of summations, you can prove the equality. It is less clear that you cannot prove the inequality without commutativity. For that you might try to show that $e^{A+B} $ involves the commutator $AB-BA $.

Comment: See this link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173088/where-we-have-used-the-condition-that-st-ts-i-e-commutativity

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll want to see the Trotter product formula. For any complex $A,B$ matrices we have
$$ \exp ( A + B ) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \left [ \exp \left ( \frac{A}{N} \right) \exp \left ( \frac{B}{N} \right ) \right ] ^N $$
You'll have the equality of $e^{A+B} = e^{A} e^{B}$ when you expand the product and you have commutativity.

Answer (score 0):

The exponential of a matrix is defined by the Taylor Series expansion

The basic reason is that in the expression on the right the $A$s appear before the $B$s but on the left hand side they can be mixed up .
Expanding to second order in $A$ and $B$ the equality reads

$$ e^{A+B} =e^A e^B $$ $$\implies   1+A+B+\frac 12 (A^2+AB+BA+B^2)=(1+A+\frac 12 A^2)(1+B+\frac 12B^2)+\text{ higher order terms }$$

The constants and the first order terms cancel. Truncating at second order we get
$$\frac 12 (AB+BA)=AB \implies AB=BA$$

Comment: $e^{A+B}=e^Ae^B$ does not imply $AB=BA$.

Comment: @loupblanc I think it "almost does": I seem to recall something like $e^{A+B}=e^A e^B e^{-(AB-BA)/2}$, or something similar. If I remember this correctly, then $e^{A+B}=e^A e^B$ implies $AB=BA$ unless you're working in the complex numbers. (An interesting question: can you have $AB-BA=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \pi i & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \pi i \end{bmatrix}$?)

Comment: Your first formula holds when (for example)  $[A,B]$ commute with $A,B$. For the last part, take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-\pi\\\pi&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B$ be a matrix that does not commute with $A$.